# Custom SORT BY SQL

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access-2013

I'm new to the community but have referenced it many times in the past.  I have an issue I'm trying to overcome in Access, specifically with a SORT BY issue in SQL.

Long story short, I need to create a report based on the results of several different queries.  I used a Union query to skirt the "Query is too complex" issue.  The results of the query aren't in the order I'd like them, though.

Since this UNION query is not based on one specific table, rather the results of many queries, I'm not able to sort by a specific column header.

I want to sort the results by the way they are written in the SQL statement.  Can anyone provide some insight to how to do this?  I've attempted several different ways but always end up with an error message.  Here's the code, and any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT [Aqua-Anvil_Total].Expr1
FROM [Aqua-Anvil_Total];
UNION SELECT [Aqua-Reslin_Total].Expr1
FROM [Aqua-Reslin_Total];
UNION SELECT [Aqua_Zenivex_Total].Expr1
FROM [Aqua_Zenivex_Total];
UNION SELECT [Aqualuer_20-20_Total].Expr1
FROM [Aqualuer_20-20_Total];
UNION SELECT [Avalon_Total].Expr1
FROM [Avalon_Total];
UNION SELECT [BVA_13_Total].Expr1
FROM [BVA_13_Total];
UNION SELECT [Deltagard_Total].Expr1
FROM [Deltagard_Total];
UNION SELECT [Envion_Total].Expr1
FROM [Envion_Total];
UNION SELECT [Scourge_18-54_Total].Expr1
FROM [Scourge_18-54_Total];
UNION SELECT [Zenivex_E20_Total].Expr1
FROM [Zenivex_E20_Total];
```

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ :please look at this link to improve question

Comment: is this MS Access? if so tag it correctly please.

Comment: @forklift Yes, I tried SORT BY 1, but the order of the results are the same.  Thanks

Comment: get rid of the `;` and add `order by 1` to the end

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `union all` instead of `union`, so if you are using `union` to remove duplicates, there would be more work to do after this.

```
select Expr1 
from (
  select [Aqua-Anvil_Total].Expr1, 0 as sort
  from [Aqua-Anvil_Total]
  union all select [Aqua-Reslin_Total].Expr1, 1 as sort
  from [Aqua-Reslin_Total]
  union all select [Aqua_Zenivex_Total].Expr1, 2 as sort
  from [Aqua_Zenivex_Total]
  union all select [Aqualuer_20-20_Total].Expr1, 3 as sort
  from [Aqualuer_20-20_Total]
  union all select [Avalon_Total].Expr1, 4 as sort
  from [Avalon_Total]
  union all select [bva_13_Total].Expr1, 5 as sort
  from [bva_13_Total]
  union all select [Deltagard_Total].Expr1, 6 as sort
  from [Deltagard_Total]
  union all select [Envion_Total].Expr1, 7 as sort
  from [Envion_Total]
  union all select [Scourge_18-54_Total].Expr1, 8 as sort
  from [Scourge_18-54_Total]
  union all select [Zenivex_E20_Total].Expr1, 9 as sort
  from [Zenivex_E20_Total]
) as u
order by u.sort
```

Comment: I completely missed the "I want to sort the results by the way they are written in the SQL statement."  Good catch.  You could `order by 2` and not have the sub query

Comment: @DanAndrews You could, but then you would have the extra column.

Comment: I'm going back to bed :D

Comment: @SqlZim Thanks, when running the code I got a Syntax error in FROM clause

Comment: semicolon's need to be removed in subquery (9 of 'em)

Comment: @sqlZim EXCELLENT!  I used the code but removed the semi-colon's and it worked like a charm!  Thank you VERY much!  Obviously I'm a novice but I appreciate everyone's willingness to help.   Restores my faith in humanity!!